# mysql query doesn't execute after reimport of data, which was working fine before

Tags: mysql

Not sure what I have missed, but I had emptied the table and did a reimport, but after that the query just keeps processing, couldn't make what I might have missed, here is the query.

```
SELECT `order1`.* 
FROM `order1` 
    LEFT JOIN `order_item` ON `order1`.`id` = `order_item`.`order_id`
    LEFT JOIN `location` ON `order_item`.`location_id` = `location`.`id` 
ORDER BY `id` DESC 
LIMIT 20;
```

The same query was returning result within seconds.
The order_item table has about 92000 records and order1 table is having around 18000 records.

Note:
in `order1` - `id` is primary key and `create_by` column is indexed
and in `order_item` - `order_id`, `location_id` is indexed.

just a update:
if I am doing a `inner join` instead, I am getting the result immediately, but the issue is the above query is being run by Yii2 for gridview and more importantly was running fine before.

**further update:**

On further testing I noticed that in the above query if I just remove the `order by` clause, it's working fine.

Comment: You emptied the tables, and then reimported the tables and now the query which used to run no longer runs???!!!! Do you think it would be better to check the import rather than showing us a basically irrelvant query? Maybe show us the schema. Do you have data in the tales? Does a simple query return rows from these tables?

Comment: yes simple query return rows just fine. but the above query is just hangs.